# How to use Java to download Report from JIRA

Tags: java, jira

I am trying to download the JIRA Tempo report by below java code but fail. May I know is that possible or how to do this? I think the main issue is cannot get the login auth as I only can download the login pages. Thanks.

```
public static void saveFile(URL url, String file) throws IOException {
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            String password = "XXXXX";
            String username = "XXXXX";
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
        }
    });

    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(file));

    int length = -1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    fos.close();
    in.close();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://XXXX.atlassian.net/TempoProjectBoardXXXX");
        String fileName = "report.xls";
        saveFile(url, fileName);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain how it fais. We aren't mind readers here

Comment: I only can donwload the login page instead of the excel report. I am not sure how to code the login auth part and I can download the report by the URL via chrome.

Comment: Did you found a way to get report?